# Tag subscription email not being delivered (2018–2019 edition)

Tags: bug, status-completed, email-notification, subscription

I just noticed that I haven't been receiving any tag subscription/filter email — since September 4, 2018!

I've checked my tag subscriptions and they each say:

> **Email Updates**
>   Subscribe to receive emails of new questions in this filter.
>   You can receive emails every 15 minutes, every 3 hours, or daily.
>   Emailing **every day** to
>   **kpreid@switchb.org**
>   edit   unsubscribe

My one filter subscription says the above plus "Confirmation email sent. Please confirm your subscription.", but asking it to resend does not generate any email. (I don't know if that filter ever worked.)

- I've checked my spam and mail filters — nothing there of note.
- I am receiving newsletters and inbox notifications successfully.
- I've seen previous mentions of the subscription system being broken but not more recently than July 2018.

---

**Update:** I still have not received any tag subscription email, despite the April 11 fix. I received a subscription confirmation email after requesting one, but no actual subscriptions.

Comment: Oh, good point -- mine's gone missing too.  And here I thought people just didn't have new questions on some of those tags!  Should have noticed the absence of [featured] here on meta, though.

Comment: @MonicaCellio It's rather a classic “noticing when something doesn't happen” problem, isn't it.

Comment: Is this working again?  It looks like some of the queueing problems have been fixed and all of your confirmed subscriptions have a `LastEmailDate` of Mar 26 or later. https://stackexchange.com/filters/1759/twisted should have arrived recently.

Comment: "Resend" also appears to be working for me.

Comment: @BrianNickel I just checked and my mailbox still contains no recent subscription messages. Found and clicked a “resend” link and there's no immediate email either.

Comment: :( I'm still looking for an issue on our end but haven't been able to reproduce the issue.  Could it be ending up in spam?

Comment: @BrianNickel I check my spam filter regularly (and right this second, too). And note that _newsletter_ email works fine.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Are you also still having this issue?  I'm going to have SRE check some logs so it would be helpful to have a accounts to look at.

Comment: @BrianNickel yes, still no notifications.  Here on MSE I tried unsubscribing and resubscribing to "featured", thinking that might kick something loose, and that's when I realized we *can't* subscribe any more, only mark tags as favorites.  So I have a mix of old-style subscriptions and new-style favorites, all marked to send me email, and I haven't gotten tag email in months.  Nothing in spam and all the Stack domains are whitelisted (se.con, so.com, and so.email -- any others?)

Comment: Thanks! I'll hand that info off.  (I am sorry you can't subscribe on-site anymore, Teams-style tag notifications were supposed to be a follow-on project.)

Comment: @BrianNickel correction -- I just found a lone message from April 2 in the spamtrap (missed whitelisting one address).  I feel like I should have had more.

Comment: @BrianNickel that lone message (for technical-writing on Writing.SE, Apr 2) seems to be an outlier.  For example, [this featured question asked yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326560/162102) didn't generate any email, and I'd be astonished if none of my several subscribed tags have had new questions in the last week.  In fact, "favorite tags" on my network profile shows a subscription and many new questions.  Other email from stackoverflow.email (like newsletters) comes through fine.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Based on the application's audit logs, it is seeing the new questions and *thinks* it's sending you emails.  I had to hand it off to another team to check the SMTP email server logs to see if it's dropping the emails or getting errors pushing to you.  The funny thing is I am getting the emails, on my personal account even, so the end-to-end system is working some of the time.  We'll have to see what they say.

Comment: Thanks @BrianNickel.  Is there a better way to track my support issue than comments on this post?  I have all three domains whitelisted at both pobox (forwarder) and gmail (where the email actually lands), and I'm not sure what else to do on my end.  AFAIK I hadn't changed anything around the time the messages stopped coming (but, of course, users always say that).

Comment: @MonicaCellio You've done plenty.  I've included this question in my ticket and I can loop back with you if we need to do testing or anything.

Comment: @BrianNickel Oh, in case it turns out to be relevant, my mail is also forwarded — through gandi.net to Gmail.

Comment: @KevinReid We changed the server configuration. Can you try resending the confirmation email and see if you get it?

Comment: @BrianNickel I got a confirmation email for subscribing to a filter! Should I expect to need to redo my tag subscriptions, or does this mean that all email should be working now?

Comment: Confirmation should mean it's working!  No need to do anything else.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Pinging you just to let you know the issue should be fixed.  Let me know if you continue to not get emails.

Comment: @BrianNickel I got email about one of my subscribed tags a few hours ago.  Thanks!

Comment: @BrianNickel Update: I have not received any question subscription email (and I've checked that there have been new questions in my filters and tag subscriptions since the fix), only the confirmation and newsletters. :(

Comment: @KevinReid if you're using the "all subscribed tags" filter, try resyncing it.  I don't know if that's relevant or a red herring, but I did it a few times in the process of poking at things.  Alas, there is no longer a way to subscribe *individually* to tags; my pre-existing subscriptions (that I didn't delete for testing, thinking I could re-add them) seem to be working, but for anything I wasn't already subscribed to, that roll-up filter seems to be the only option.  (Which is frustrating because it's not segregated by site.)  Anyway, try resyncing that and see if it helps.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I wasn't previously using “Favorite Tags” (I assume that's what you meant) subscription, but I tried turning it on at 15-minute frequency and it's been at least 30 minutes with no email. (Though the confirmation does say "within 24 hours"…)

Comment:  I can look at it again next week. This is a frustrating issue since it looks like it’s working and I literally got my daily subscription 3 hours ago.

Comment: Well, lookit that. I just got a Favorite Tags email. But none of my other subscriptions (even the other filter subscription) have delivered … I _suppose_ I could use exclusively Favorite Tags. Awkward.

Comment: @BrianNickel might the same server-configuration problem have affected other email?  I hit 100k in December and never received the congratulations email, and belatedly I wonder if it's the same problem.  I don't know what other infrequently-sent email y'all generate, but I was looking out for that one so I know I never saw it.

Answer (score 7):

This is fixed.

This was one of the few remaining instances where we send emails via an internal SMTP server.  At some point we switched to using an `@stackoverflow.email` address but we weren't signing the outgoing emails with the DKIM key we use for other emails.  This caused other email systems view tag subscriptions as untrustworthy and drop them.

We're now sending these emails to our normal email delivery service and they're getting signed correctly.

Comment: Wow, so it was getting dropped even before it got to my whitelist, apparently?  Yikes, I didn't know that could happen.  Now I have to find out how to turn it off.

Comment: Thanks for the fix and the details!

Comment: @MonicaCellio I don't know all the details, but you probably don't want to turn it off. DKIM is a way for senders to vouch for the authenticity of an email, reducing the risk of fraud. (Anyone can technically send an email from any address so some automated filtering is warranted. In fact, I used to spoof email addresses all the time using AltaVista's flexible "from" editor.)

Comment: @BrianNickel true, I don't want to turn it off, but for things that seem to be from addresses I've *whitelisted*, I'd rather it not be silent either.  Oh well.  (And yes, I figured out how to spoof email not long after getting access to email, so I realize the dangers. :-) )

Comment: I'm having the same problem trying to subscribe to my Favorite Tags (https://stackexchange.com/filters/103309/favorite-tags) I'm getting no confirmation email at all.

Comment: This isn't fixed. I'm having the same problem in October 2019.

Comment: Same issue for me. I wonder if it doesnt work for filter tags. Please can someone guide on any way to subscribe to a single tag? Because "subscribe" option is not there for a single tag. So then what's the bypass solution as of now? :-(

Comment: Not fixed. I have the same problem now, in Nov 2019. Why to allow specifying separate email for subscriptions if we have account email which can be served for everything?