# Cannot confirm email subscription

Tags: support, email-notification

I am trying to subscribe to [this filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/377791/quantum-computing).
It seems that I am in fact subscribed, but I'm not getting mail.
Now, I *used* to get email from this filter, but around January of 2018 it just stopped sending me mail.
When I view the filter page now, there's a box on the right side that says *"Confirmation email sent. Please confirm your subscription."*
So, I clicked "resend confirmation email" but haven't gotten any confirmation email.

Advice?

Comment: I have the same problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330246/filter-subscription-email-is-not-being-delivered-june-july-2019-edition I hope this gets fixed soon!