# Not receiving email confirmation on My filtered tags

Tags: bug, email, tag-filters, tag-watching, confirmation

I have tried to subscribe to my required tags for every 3 hours. But it just doesn't work. I have also tried "resend confirmation mail"; the page says confirmation mail sent. But I have not received any mail since I have been trying.
There are many new questions and updates for these tags since 2-3 days. But I do not get any update mails either.
My subscription email id is gmail id. I have not blocked any mails in my settings.
Please note, in past I have received updates for my own questions. So getting mails inside my gmail inbox cannot be an issue.

Why I am not getting the confirmation mail from stackexchange??

Here is snapshot of how I am trying to subscribe:-
[image]

Comment: Have you checked spam/junk?

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330246/filter-subscription-email-is-not-being-delivered-june-july-2019-edition

Comment: Yes, I have checked spam everytime. The mails are not there. Note that I did receive the comment notification for this Question. But I do not receive notifications for the tags. I have checked other open issues, they are still open for some people. Please help! If there is any working way to subscribe to a single tag, that will also be helpful!!