# Tag filters not sending e-mail messages

Tags: support, tags, email

Last week I set up a few filters for tags of interest. The web page informs of a verification e-mail message, but such messages are not being sent (or somehow never reach the e-mail server).

New questions have been filed for these tags and I have not received any e-mail notification. Perhaps because the e-mail is not verified, but I can not be sure.

Is there anything I can do to start receiving these e-mails?

Comment: You're not alone: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330246/filter-subscription-email-is-not-being-delivered-june-july-2019-edition